# Aggregate function results in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Hopefully the code below should demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

The issue is that none of the input selects are resolved by the time I try to calculate `VatableCash` so I get "Invalid Column" when trying to select it.

Sorry if there's something plainly obvious I can do here. SQL isn't one of my strong suits.

```
select
    OrderHeader.ID,
    sum(OrderLine.NetPrice) as OrderLineNetPrice,
    sum(OrderLine.GrossPrice) as OrderLineGrossPrice,
    sum(
        case when PaymentOption_ID = 8
            then Payment.Amount
            else 0
        end
    ) as TotalCashAmount,
    ((OrderLineGrossPrice - OrderLineNetPrice) / OrderLineGrossPrice) * TotalCashAmount as VatableCash
    from OrderHeader
    inner join Payment on Payment.OrderHeader_ID = OrderHeader.ID
    inner join OrderLine on OrderLine.OrderHeader_ID = OrderHeader.ID
    group by OrderHeader.ID
```

Comment: You could repeat the calculations for orderlinenetprice,orderlinegrossprice and totalcashamount when calculating vatable cash, move the calculation of vatable cash to an outer query or use a cte (which is in effect the same thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use sub query.

you can try this.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    select
        OrderHeader.ID,
        sum(OrderLine.NetPrice) as OrderLineNetPrice,
        sum(OrderLine.GrossPrice) as OrderLineGrossPrice,
        sum(
            case when PaymentOption_ID = 8
                then Payment.Amount
                else 0
            end
        ) as TotalCashAmount
    from OrderHeader
        inner join Payment on Payment.OrderHeader_ID = OrderHeader.ID
        inner join OrderLine on OrderLine.OrderHeader_ID = OrderHeader.ID
    group by OrderHeader.ID
)
SELECT *, 
    ((OrderLineGrossPrice - OrderLineNetPrice) / OrderLineGrossPrice) * TotalCashAmount as VatableCash
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks! Need some time to test. Will get back to you soon!

Answer (score 2):

Love the cross apply! Use it whenever you want some handy extra columns.

```
select
    OrderHeader.ID,
    sum(OrderLine.NetPrice) as OrderLineNetPrice,
    sum(OrderLine.GrossPrice) as OrderLineGrossPrice,
    TotalCashAmount,
    ((OrderLineGrossPrice - OrderLineNetPrice) / OrderLineGrossPrice) * TotalCashAmount as VatableCash
    from OrderHeader
    inner join Payment on Payment.OrderHeader_ID = OrderHeader.ID
    inner join OrderLine on OrderLine.OrderHeader_ID = OrderHeader.ID
    cross apply ( select sum(
        case when PaymentOption_ID = 8
            then Payment.Amount
            else 0
        end
    )) as subquery(TotalCashAmount)
    group by OrderHeader.ID
```

Comment: Small issue with that is that I think I also have to do it with `OrderLineNetPrice` and `OrderLineGrossPrice` and if that's the case I'm  thinking about using the subquery solution down below. I can't test now though so I'll check them both out when I can. Thanks!

Comment: You can add these to an additional cross apply if you want:
cross apply (select sum(OrderLine.NetPrice) as OrderLineNetPrice,
    sum(OrderLine.GrossPrice) as OrderLineGrossPrice) as sumsquery